# Integration sylius Terms & Conditions Plugin

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, e-commerce, sylius

I'm trying to integrate Terms & Conditions Plugin in my sylius plugin https://github.com/Setono/SyliusTermsPlugin. I add plugin before the grid bundle, but I have always this error  "You have requested a non-existent parameter "setono_sylius_terms.model.terms.class".

This is my code:

```
# config/bundles.php
  Setono\SyliusTermsPlugin\SetonoSyliusTermsPlugin::class => ['all' => true],
  Sylius\Bundle\GridBundle\SyliusGridBundle::class => ['all' => true]

# config/packages/_sylius.yaml
   - { resource: "@SetonoSyliusTermsPlugin/Resources/config/app/config.yaml" }

# config/routes.yaml

setono_sylius_terms_shop:
   resource: "@SetonoSyliusTermsPlugin/Resources/config/shop_routing.yaml"
   prefix: /{_locale}
   requirements:
     _locale: ^[a-z]{2}(?:_[A-Z]{2})?$

setono_sylius_terms_admin:
   resource: "@SetonoSyliusTermsPlugin/Resources/config/admin_routing.yaml"
   prefix: /admin

#vendor\setono\sylius-terms-plugin\src\Resources\config\grids
  sylius_grid:
     grids:
      setono_sylius_terms_terms:
        driver:
            name: doctrine/orm
            options:
                class: "%setono_sylius_terms.model.terms.class%"
```

The Problem is on this call of class, please can anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parameter is set by the [SyliusResourceBundle](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle), so make sure `Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle` is before `SyliusTermsPlugin` and any other plugin.

As a general rule, it should be:

```
// config/bundles.php
<?php

return [
    // ...

    Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle::class => ['all' => true],

    // All Sylius plugins

    Sylius\Bundle\GridBundle\SyliusGridBundle::class => ['all' => true],

    // ...
 ];
```

Comment: Thank you, I add  SyliusResourceBundle before the other plugins but the error still exist.

Comment: Did you also add SyliusGridBundle after all plugins?

Comment: I want to add a menu in the back-end which brings together a list of product attributes, how to do it please. I try to add a new plugin that do this need but I dont know how to activate and manage it.